# How to fetch all fields of table using sequelize in nodejs?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I want to fetch all fields without to write all fields name of table. How to use * to fetch all the fields from the table ?

```
This is UserController function to fetch all the rows with all fields of table.

user.findAll({
        attributes: ['name','email','mobile','dob','address','image','is_active'],
        where:{
            is_active:'1',
            name:{$like:'%%'}
        },
        limit:10
    }).then(function(users,fields){
        console.log(users);
        res.send({error:false,message:'users list',data:users});
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log('Oops! something went wrong, : ', err);
    });

This is model code and define some property of model.

var sequalize = require('../../config/db_config');

const User = sequalize.define('user',{},{
    timestamps: false,
    paranoid: true,
    underscored: true,
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: 'user',
    createdAt:'created_on',
    updatedAt:'updated_on'
});

User.sync({force:false}).then(() => {
    console.log('Table is created!');    
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('An error occur when table is created!');
});
module.exports = User;
```

Please help me that how to fetch all fields with write to attribute in controller.

Answer (score 4):

Simply ommit the attributes key in your query and all the fields will return.

```
user.findAll({
  where:{
    is_active:'1',
    name:{$like:'%%'}
  },
  limit:10
}).then(function(users){
  console.log(users);
  res.send({error:false,message:'users list',data:users});
}).catch(function(err){
  console.log('Oops! something went wrong, : ', err);
});
```

EDIT: In your model definition is best if you specify the fields your table has. Like so: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html

Otherwise you will have to specify the attributes key in every find operation.

Comment: thanks for reply.  I am begginer in nodejs. How to ommit the attribute key, give an example ?

Comment: when i am ommit the attribute then it return only  id attribute.

Comment: Update your question and show us your model definition

Comment: Check my edited answer. You need to specify the fields in your model definition

Answer (score 2):

@yBrodsky is right . Also you should make model like this.so that it can know the field to select when no attribute.

```
const User = sequalize.define('user',{},{
    timestamps: false,
    paranoid: true,
    underscored: true,
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: 'user',
    createdAt:'created_on',
    updatedAt:'updated_on'
});
```

to this

var sequalize = require('../../config/db_config');

```
const User = sequalize.define('user',{
 name: {type: Sequelize.STRING},
  email: {type: Sequelize.STRING},
  mobile: {type: Sequelize.INTEGER},
  dob: {type: Sequelize.DATE}
address: {type: Sequelize.STRING},
  image: {type: Sequelize.INTEGER},
  is_active: {type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN }


},{
    timestamps: false,
    paranoid: true,
    underscored: true,
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: 'user',
    createdAt:'created_on',
    updatedAt:'updated_on'
});
```

for dtatype see here 
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#data-types

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove attributes from model , you will be able fetch all columns